# All files matching the following patterns are ignored - why?

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

The directory structure in the Angular project I'm working on is as follows (reduced to the relevant files):

```
project
  |- libs
  |    |- utils
  |         |- common
  |              |- src
  |              |    |- lib
  |              |         |- model
  |              |         |    |- translation
  |              |         |         |- translation-helper.ts (3)
  |              |         |- utils-common.module.ts
  |              |- .eslintrc.json (2)
  |              |- project.json
  |- .eslintrc.json (1)
```

For further reference, I have numbered the files.

The `.eslintrc.json` files make some statements about file inclusion/exclusion:

(1) starts like this:

```json
{
    "root": true,
    "ignorePatterns": ["**/*"],
```

(2) starts like this:

```json
{
    "extends": ["../../../.eslintrc.json"],
    "ignorePatterns": ["!**/*"],
```

Note that *I think* no-one in the team has written that code; I think it's all part of the whole bunch of files that nx generates automatically for all modules. That notwithstanding, based on the [docs for `.eslintrc.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/npmrc?v=true), I think it makes sense and should work - globally, all files are excluded, which is overridden per module by negating (hence the `!` pattern) the wildcard exclusion (and possibly then declaring more specific exclusions).

---

Now, I'm trying to run ESLint for file (3):

```
npx nx lint utils-common --files=**/model/translation/translation-helper.ts
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following output:

```
Linting "utils-common"...

 >  NX   All files matching the following patterns are ignored:

   - 'libs/utils/common/src/**/*.ts'

   Please check your '.eslintignore' file.
   Pass --verbose to see the stacktrace.
```

There are no `.eslintignore` files in the directory hierarchy.

Also, I am very sure file (2) *is* picked up by ESLint, for if e.g. the path indicated in `extends` of (2) is wrong (for example, having one directory level too much or too little), ESLint *does* output a corresponding error.

Lastly, ESLint will happily lint if I remove the `**/*` ignore pattern from (1), but I feel that was not the intention of whichever person/tool/template put that ignore pattern there in the first place. Also, I want to understand why it doesn't work the way it is configured now.

---

**What is going on here? Why does ESLint claim all of my files are excluded?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `ignorePatterns` do indeed work as I describe.

However, file (2) also contained the following in its `overloads` section:

```json
"files": ["*.ts"],
"extends": [
    "plugin:@nrwl/nx/angular",
    "../../../.eslintrc.json"
],
```

This caused file (1) to be included *again*, including the original `ignorePatterns` with `**/*`, thereby circumventing my adaptation of the `ignorePatterns` above in file (2).

The solution I am choosing is to have an additional root `.eslintrc.json` file (with a different name), which defines the base for individual rules to override. Then, from within the `overrides`, I can extend from that file, whereas the global `extends` attribute will point to the original root file.

Comment: Does this work, your solution? I have the same problem, but even with your hints I am unable to get rid of this error

Comment: @grenobnik: Yes, it works for me as described here.

Comment: For me, the issue was caused by a manual rename. I reverted the manual stuff and used `nx mv` which worked perfectly.